# How to prevent cables from getting tangled in the wheels of a rolling rack?

Tags: cable, rack

I currently have at home an 42U server cabinet (which I am very happy with `;)` ).
Since those things are really big, its current location is not that optimal, but it works. It stands against the wall, and if I want to access the back I have to move the cabinet a little. This is not ideal, but is okay for now.

The problem I am currently running into is that the cables get snagged. When I move the cabinet the cables move along and I am afraid that one will get stuck in the wheels.

How can I solve or mitigate this problem? 
For example, is there some kind of mechanism that can move when moving the cabinet? Something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Tuinslang.JPG), but for cables, of course, and that could fit inside the cabinet? Maybe there is something that puts a little pressure on the cables and when moving back to the wall that it automatically rolls it back up.

Or maybe there is something that I could put or attach to the floor that moves along?

Does this exist, and what is its name?

I know moving a cabinet is not ideal, but there is simply no better option right now. I have checked the amount that it can handle on the wheels and checked the weight of the components to see if I am on the right side of the threshold.

No product/shopping recommendations, please.

Comment: Note ethernet cables are not meant to be rolled up smaller than a specified bend radius otherwise they will be damaged.

Comment: Good point of course, but maybe the roll is that big that it is not a problem anymore. I realize that but good to bring that up. Also a note would be that will there be any type of induction occurring when a couple of cables are attached?

Comment: Use shorter cables that don't reach the floor?

Comment: Of course, I try to minimize the length but some cables can not be shorted. For example the PDU cable has a fixed length and I am not up for opening it up and attaching a new cable. I have to move it around 1 meter from the wall to get to the back. This of course who short the cable is make it hang on the floor when pushing it back again

Comment: Not a recommendation, or suggestion, http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=retract+ethernet+cables  but for personal use when all other factors are known, retract cables are awesome.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your situation (maybe you could post a photograph), but searches for "cable hook", "cable tie", and "cable trough" yield devices that might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### When I move the cabinet the cables move along

> and I am afraid that at the certain moment one will get stuck in the wheels

**Solution 1:**

You can use a pulley system.

- Buy a pulley:

[image]

- Attach the pulley to the wall.
- The pulley needs to be attached to the wall **more** than 1 meter above the height where the cables will hang when the cabinet is against the wall (this allows you to move the cabinet by 1 meter as required).
- Run a length of cord though the pulley.
- Attach one end of the cord to the cabinet.
- Make a loop in the other end of the cord around the cables.
- When you move the cabinet it will pull on the cord and lift the cables.
- Use trial and error to make the cord the right length.
- The correct cord length will keep the cables off the floor when the cabinet is against the wall and allow at least 1 meter of movement before the cables get close the the pulley

**Solution 2:**

- Have a 2nd pulley attached to the cabinet.
- Put a loop at both ends of the cord.
- Attach both loops **to each other** and around the cables.
- Then the cables would lift in the middle between the wall and the cabinet instead of next to the wall.
- This may put less stress on the cables.

Comment: Actually a very neat idea for the situation.

Comment: You could also have a 2nd pulley attached to the cabinet. Put a loop on both ends of the cord. Attached both loops **together** around the cables. Then the cables would lift in the middle instead of next to the wall. I'm not sure whether this would put less stress on the cables. Answer updated.

Comment: Great, great, great, many thanks! That could be it. Just saying that if any vendor of rack equipment is reading this, maybe an idea to make this as addon for an rack??

Answer (score 4):

You can hang the mid-point of the cable bundle from elastic/rubber band etc depending on load, fastened to either the wall or cabinet, or for a longer stretch from ⅓ & ⅔ points, one elastic to each, wall & cabinet, in reverse order.

It's an old audio engineer's trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are devices like this:

[image: diagram of cable arm]

They hold the cables and fold or unfold as they are pulled or pushed. These devices exist to solve the stated problem.

I found this by searching for "cable arm".

Comment: I don't really think this is gonna work. Mainly because the doors needs to be open to back and forth with the cabinet. The cabinet is a closed one and  it would be even worse to leave the doors open all the time than preventing the cables from running over. But as of my question it is not clear if it is an open or closed rack, so this answer can be of help for others. So thanks anyway